# How to include network credentials in Neo4JClient?

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

So tipically if you install Neo4j in your development environment, you will have a local hosted version of the Neo4Jserver, which usually you can browse with: localhost:7474/db/data.

Your code is like this:

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
client.Connect();
```

However, one day you will want to connect to your Cloud-based Neo4J Server (Heroku, Azure, etc.) 
Of course, that means you will have to provide Network credentials. 
If you only use your bare hands, it could be like this:

```
var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://<<your_REST_query"));
var cred = new NetworkCredential("yourusername", "yourpassword");

http.Credentials = cred;

var response = http.GetResponse();
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

But how can I include network credentials to connect with Neo4JClient? or is there another option that I don't know?

Comment: The constructor for GraphClient does accept a IHttpClient, not sure if that might tie the two together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We support the standard URI syntax for basic authentication credentials:

```
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://user:pass@localhost:7474/db/data"));
```

Comment: This is now documented on https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/wiki/connecting

Comment: Do your username or password have a colon or @ symbol in them? If not, please open an issue at https://bitbucket.org/Readify/neo4jclient/issues/new so that we can identify and fix the bug.

Comment: No, they are just alphanumeric randomly generated by Heroku. var `graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://LOGIN:PASSWORD@SERVER.hosted.neo4j.org:7259/db/data"));graphClient.Connect();` also with a trailing slash. Just want to make sure it's not me doing something stupid.

Answer (score 0):

From [version 1.1.0.0](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/connecting)

```
var username = "app_username"
var password = "1@mGr@phG0d"    
var client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"), username, password);
```